# How is the "Corresponding requests per minute (RPM)" calculated when creating a GPT deployment in Azure?

Tags: gpt, openai, azure

I created an Azure OpenAI resource in my Azure account. I want to deploy a GPT-4-32k model.
How is the "Corresponding requests per minute (RPM)" calculated when creating a GPT deployment in Azure? E.g., in the example below, why do 1k tokens per minute correspond to 6 requests per minute?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that this fetching of tokens leads to lags in the chat as well? See [What can be done if ChatGPT 3.5 becomes unresponsive while working on an answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173439/253420), which shows that refreshing the website sometimes triggers the laggy chatbot to go further.